# Using a user-set variable in an awk command

Tags: if-statement, awk, user-defined

I'm trying to use awk with a user-defined variable (`$EVENT`, where `$EVENT` is a filename and also a column in a textfile) in the if condition, but it doesn't seem to recognize the variable. I've tried with various combinations of ', ", { and ( but nothing seem to work.

```
EVENT=19971010_1516.txt
awk '{if ($2=="$EVENT") print $3,$4,$8}' FILENAME.txt > output.txt
```

It is possible to use user-defined variables in `awk` commands? If so, how does the syntax work?

Answer (score 3):

you cannot use `$FOO` directly in your code, because awk will think it is column `FOO`. (FOO is variable). but your FOO is empty. to use shell var, use `-v` like:

```
awk -v event="$EVENT" '{print event}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
awk '$2==event {print $3,$4,$8}' event="$EVENT" FILENAME.txt > output.txt
```

```
awk -v event="$EVENT" '$2==event {print $3,$4,$8}' FILENAME.txt > output.txt
```

See this post for more info:
[How do I use shell variables in an awk script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script/19075707#19075707)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include the variable in the awk script literally then you need to enclose the script in double quotes (single quotes do not expand variables). So something like `awk '{if ($2=="'"$EVENT"'") print $3,$4,$8}' FILENAME.txt > output.txt'`. Which uses single quotes on the rest of the awk script to avoid needing to escape the <kbd>$</kbd> characters but then uses double quotes for the event variable.

That being said you almost certainly want to expose the shell variable to awk as an awk variable which means you want to use the `-v` flag to awk. So something like `awk -vevent="$EVENT" '{if ($2==event) print $3,$4,$8}' FILENAME.txt > output.txt`. (Alternatively you could use something like `awk '{if ($2==event) print $3,$4,$8}' event="$EVENT" FILENAME.txt > output.txt`.)

You could also simplify your awk body a bit by using `'$2 == event {print $3,$4,$8}'` and let patterns do what they are supposed to do.